# ¿Cómo crear un ciclo de análisis de datos en SQL?

Tags: sql-server, datatables, sql

Hola a todos tengo una consulta ya me da los datos que requiero solo que quiero un poco mas, lo que quiero hacer pero no se como se maneja en sql es que con estos datos que tengo me arroje la mejor opción en base a mi costo.

Es una orden de compra que realiza el usuario con esta orden de compra el sistema analiza si fue la mejor opción en base a a una lista de precios con diferentes proveedores

Este es mi codigo

```
SELECT
A1.PO_No,A7.Name,A1.Supplier_No,A5.Supplier_Code,A2.Line_Item_No,
A3.Item_No,A3.Description,A2.Unit_Price,A2.Unit,A1.Currency_Code,
A4.Supplier_No,A6.Supplier_Code,
A4.Unit_Price,A4.Lead_Time FROM Purchasing_v_PO_e A1
INNER JOIN Purchasing_v_Line_Item_e A2 ON A1.PO_Key = A2.PO_Key
INNER JOIN Purchasing_v_Item_e A3 ON A3.Item_Key = A2.Item_Key
INNER JOIN Purchasing_v_Item_Supplier_Price_e A4 ON A4.Item_Key = A2.Item_Key
LEFT JOIN Common_v_Supplier_e A5 ON A5.Supplier_No =  A1.Supplier_No
LEFT JOIN Common_v_Supplier_e A6 ON A6.Supplier_No =  A4.Supplier_No
LEFT JOIN Common_v_Department_e A7 on A7.Department_No = A1.Department_No
where A7.Name = @DEPARTAMENTO
```

tengo una orden de compra.

estos son los campos de mi orden de compra

A1.PO_No (Numero de orden de compra)
A1.Supplier_No (Proveedor de la orden de compra)
A2.Line_Item_No (Artículos por linea)
A2.Unit_Price (Precio unitario de la orden de compra)

y los quiero comparar con una lista de precios que tengo para que me regrese si con el proveedor que tengo mi orden es el mejor en base al precio.

A4.Supplier_No (ID_Proveedor en la lista de precios)
A4.Unit_Price ( Predio de la lista de precios)
A4.Lead_Time (tiempo de entrega de la lista de precios)

entonces lo que requiero es primero sacar mi mejor precio de ese articulo que quiero comprar y luego compara el precio entre mi orden de compra y el precio de mi lista.

Comment: Hola. No eres novato así que te comento sin introducción: Recuerda no usar mayúsculas sostenidas en el título ni en la pregunta. Aquí se lee eso como gritar y pues... no es agradable para los otros usuarios :). Por favor, edita la pregunta

Comment: @Alfabravo como acotación tú comentario, creo tampoco fue muy amable.

Comment: Yo no veo nada de malo o poco amable en el comentario de @AlfaBravo

Answer (score 0):

creo que ya lo tengo

```html
SELECT 

A1.PO_No,A7.Name,A1.Supplier_No,A5.Supplier_Code,A2.Line_Item_No,
A3.Item_No,A3.Description,A2.Unit_Price,A2.Unit,A1.Currency_Code,
A4.Supplier_No,A6.Supplier_Code,
A4.Unit_Price,A4.Lead_Time,

CASE 
WHEN A2.Unit_Price > (SELECT MIN( Unit_Price) FROM Purchasing_v_Item_Supplier_Price_e
WHERE Item_Key = A2.Item_Key)  THEN 'EXISTE UN MEJOR PRECIO'
WHEN A2.Unit_Price <= (SELECT MIN( Unit_Price) FROM Purchasing_v_Item_Supplier_Price_e
WHERE Item_Key = A2.Item_Key) THEN 'NO'
END,
(SELECT MIN( Unit_Price) FROM Purchasing_v_Item_Supplier_Price_e
WHERE Item_Key = A2.Item_Key)


FROM Purchasing_v_PO_e A1
INNER JOIN Purchasing_v_Line_Item_e A2 ON A1.PO_Key = A2.PO_Key
INNER JOIN Purchasing_v_Item_e A3 ON A3.Item_Key = A2.Item_Key
INNER JOIN Purchasing_v_Item_Supplier_Price_e A4 ON A4.Item_Key = A2.Item_Key
LEFT JOIN Common_v_Supplier_e A5 ON A5.Supplier_No =  A1.Supplier_No
LEFT JOIN Common_v_Supplier_e A6 ON A6.Supplier_No =  A4.Supplier_No
LEFT JOIN Common_v_Department_e A7 on A7.Department_No = A1.Department_No
where A7.Name = 'Produccion'
```

lo pueden revisar y ver si se puede mejorar